Cron is not inheriting environment variables in Docker container
I am trying to run cron inside a Docker container to periodically update my database, perform backups, etc. Here is my cron job configuration:
*/1 * * * * (. /app/.env.development; echo $DJANGO_COLOR) >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
*/1 * * * * (. /app/.env.development; /usr/local/bin/python3 /app/src/manage.py command) >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
*/1 * * * * (export $(cat /app/.env.development | grep -v "^#" | xargs); /usr/local/bin/python3 /app/src/manage.py command) >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1

The problem:
The cron job does not inherit the environment variables from my Docker container.
I tried loading the environment variables with . /app/.env.development, which works for the first line, but for some reason, the Django server runs without the environment variables in the second and third lines.
The cronjob Dockerfile:
FROM app as cron

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Copy hello-cron file to the cron.d directory
COPY cron/app-cron /etc/cron.d/app-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/app-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/app-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

Entrypoint: /bin/bash -c "cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log"
Can you please explain why this is happening? How can I ensure that the cron job correctly loads the environment variables from the .env file?

The Dockerfile you show doesn't mention an /app directory at all; how does the file you're looking for get there?  What leads you to believe the environment variables aren't set?  Any reason to not put CMD cron -f in the Dockerfile, so the cron daemon runs without exiting as the main container process?

I solved it with this cronjob file:
*/1 * * * * (/bin/bash -c '/app/src/cron-daily.sh') >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1

and this script file used as job:
#!/bin/bash

# Export all variables from the .env.development file
set -o allexport
source /app/.env.development
set +o allexport

# Continue with what ever that needs your env variables
...

